# What are the places to visit in Kullu Manali

Tags: air-travel

I am planning to visit Kullu Manali this year end. Can you help me providing details about the best places to visit in Kullu Manali.

Comment: Welcome to Travel SE! Unfortunately, "best" is a subjective term. While I may like crowded streets and shopping areas, another person may be looking for peace and quiet. Questions that are subjective are considered off-topic and may be closed. Please [edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/100397/edit) your question to add more details, such as places you have short-listed and activities that you have in mind. Please note that questions that ask for itinerary planning are also off-topic.